# Master-detail Cognos report with parameter

Tags: report, master-detail, cognos

I need to create a report using two data sources in cognos 10.
A master source has a "column" named id which i want to use as second data source parameter.
I create a master detail relationship from id to my parameter, but to all details id from first row is passed.

How to change it to a situation where id from row is passed?

[image: a image illustrating what i want to achieve]

A detail(x) is a effect of second data source with passed parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using two different queries and two different list objects. The detail list should be nested inside the parent list. They should then be linked via the Master-Detail Relationships property. Double-check the join, as many developers are prone to misclicks on this screen.

[Here is a good walkthrough](http://wiki.centre.edu/its/index.php/Master-Detail_Relationship_in_Cognos) on creating what I described above.

Comment: The walkthrough is for a join not a parameter, but folowing the steps and choosing parameter instead of column from other query also give me a wrong data. Cognos only get id from first row and repeat it for detail of every other row.